# Order in which Cypress commands are run

Tags: asynchronous, cypress

It's my understanding that since Javascript is asynchronous , the Cypress framework is also asynchronous . This means that 1) Cypress commands are queued up and  run in the order in which they were queued up and 2) that the second Cypress command doesn't wait for the first Cypress command to finish .

I have a question about the below scenario where we click on the kebab menu and then click on a particular kebab menu item .Note, it's important that the kebab menu be clicked before the  kebab menu item is clicked. This seems to work fine. Is it just fluke that it works fine ?
Why haven't I run into the issue where the second command is run before the first command is finished ?

```
kebabmenu = "a.pf-c-dropdown__menu";
kebabmenuItem = "#delete";

cy.get(kebabmenu).click();
cy.get(kebabmenuItem).click;
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your example uses **static items**, i.e defined in the page before loading. In that case, the test commands can proceed in order and at full speed.

But if you had an API or external service **populating the items in a lazy fashion**, i.e sending a fetch request upon `cy.get(kebabmenu).click()`, then Cypress does not know when the list items populated.

In that case you can indeed execute the second command too early. You need to add some code to stall the ***kebabmenuItem*** `click()`.

Two ways I can see

- add an `intercept` for the fetch and `cy.wait('@intercept')`
- add an assertion about the length of the list

Example(s)

```js
cy.intercept('some-url-fetching-items').as('@intercept')   // listen for fetch

cy.get(kebabmenu).click()                                // initiates the fetch

cy.wait('@intercept')                                  // wait for intercept response

cy.get('#items')
  .should('have.length', 'gt', 0)                    // retry until items populated

cy.get(kebabmenuItem).click()                      // action on required item
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second point is wrong. The Cypress commands are run in a sequential deterministic order.
Here is an excerpt from [the official docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#You-cannot-race-or-run-multiple-commands-at-the-same-time):

> You cannot race or run multiple commands at the same time (in parallel).

> Cypress guarantees that it will execute all of its commands and queries deterministically and identically every time they are run.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress commands are asynchronous but they still wait for the previous one to succeed (or not).
Meaning if `cy.get(kebabmenu).click()` fails, the test will stop and not proceed to the next command.

In case `kebabmenuItem` is not visible before `kebabmenu` is clicked, you are covered, since by calling `cy.get(kebabmenuItem)`, cypress by default makes sure the element is present in the DOM (using a [default timeout](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration)).

In case both elements are visible from the beginning and something else happens when you click `kebabmenu` that needs to finish before you click `kebabmenuItem`, you could implement a wait for whatever that something is before you execute `cy.get(kebabmenuItem).click;`